# Apache Mina: how to get the IP from a connected client

Tags: java, apache-mina

Can anyone tell me how the get the IP address from a connected client?

So far I've found

```
session.getRemoteAddress().toString()
```

and returns something like

> /192.168.1.100:49879

is this ok? Can I do something that can return only 192.168.1.100 ?

When I used Sockets I was using something like:

```
socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
```

is there something similar using IoSession in apache mina?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Downcast the `SocketAddress` returned by `getRemoteAddress()` to a `InetSocketAddress`.  You can then call `getAddress()` which will return an `InetAddress` object that has the `getHostAddress()` method you're used to.

e.g.

```
InetSocketAddress socketAddress = (InetSocketAddress) session.getRemoteAddress();
InetAddress inetAddress = socketAddress.getAddress();

inetAddress.getHostAddress();
```